# How to extract data based on 2 columns in a data frame and make a new column using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in my data frame. “adult” represents the number of adults in a hotel room and “children” represents the number of children in a room.

I want to create a new column based on these two. 
For example if `df['adults'] == 2 and df[‘children’]==0` the value of the new column would be "couple with no children". 
And if the `df['adults'] = 2 and df[‘children’]=1` the value of the new column would be "couple with 1 child".

I have a big amount of data and I want the code to run fast.

Any advice? This is a sample of the inputs and the output that I need.

```
adult children   family_status

2       0       "Couple without children"     
2       0       "Couple without children"
2       1       "Couple with one child"
```

Comment: What should be values if `adults` are more than 2 or less than 2?

Comment: For example if adult =1 the value can be "single". The adult unique values are 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question and expected output covering all the cases? It would be helpful.

Comment: Add the details to the question. It's very cryptic in comments

Comment: I'm so sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: What about the status if data doesn't have all those parameter defined by you? What about adults!=2 and children>=2.

Comment: In that case, we can set values to np.nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use [**`np.select`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
df
  adult  children
0      2         0
1      2         0
2      2         1

condlist = [(df['adults']==2) & (df['children']==0),(df['adults']==2) & (df['children']==1)]
choicelist = ['couple with no children','couple with 1 child']
df['family_status'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist,np.nan)
df
   adult  children            family_status
0      2         0  couple with no children
1      2         0  couple with no children
2      2         1      couple with 1 child
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but I got this error:ValueError: 

The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @yasi_ensaf My bad I messed parenthesis while editing. Check the edited answer. ;)

Comment: I edited the answer to handle cases that kriti mentioned too. ;) It will add `np.nan`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df['family_status'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'adult with no child' if (x['adult']==2 and x['children']==0)  
                        else ( 'adult with 1 child' 
                              if (x['adult']==2 and x['children']==1) else ''), axis=1)
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Check this [Avoiding apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code). Try to avoid `df.apply` as much as possible. ;) Not saying your answer is bad.